# Spring Boot and Vaadin UI not accessible?

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin

I set up a spring boot vaadin project and implemented this class according to [springs tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/crud-with-vaadin/), but cannot access the ui with localhost:8080/ui. What am I doing wrong?

My UI class:

```
package net.lawyd.server.ui;

import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.spring.annotation.SpringUI;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
import com.vaadin.ui.Notification;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;

@SpringUI(path = "/ui")
@Theme("valo")
public class VaadinUI extends UI {

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        setContent(new Button("Click me", e -> Notification.show("Hello Spring+Vaadin user!")));
    }
}
```

Here is my Spring configuration class:

```
package net.lawyd.server.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("net.lawyd.server")
@EnableJpaRepositories("net.lawyd.server")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class SpringConfig {

    // Nothing to do here

}
```

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>net.lawyd</groupId>
    <artifactId>lawyd-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

[UPDATE 1] I noticed this log message:

> Cannot enhance @Configuration bean definition
>   'com.vaadin.spring.VaadinConfiguration' since its singleton instance
>   has been created too early. The typical cause is a non-static @Bean
>   method with a BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor return type:
>   Consider declaring such methods as 'static'.

[UPDATE 2] I created an empty spring boot application using [start.spring.io](http://start.spring.io/) and inserting the demo from the tutorial. It works there, so it has to be something with my setting.

[UPDATE 3] I figured out it has something to do with the JerseyConfig, when I take it out it Vaadin works, but jersey does not anymore:

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfig() {
        register(TodoResource.class);
        register(HealthResource.class);
    }
}
```

Here is also the [code on github](https://github.com/joekienzle/lawyd/tree/feature/simpleVaadinUi).

Comment: I also tried `@EnableVaadin` at the SpringConfig which made no difference. Also tried accessing the root under localhost:8080, but nothing.

Comment: Did you start the project using "mvn spring-boot:run"?

Comment: Does not make any difference.

Comment: You need to start the project before you can open localhost:8080. Are you using Eclipse, IntelliJ, Netbeans? Or you can start it from the command line. Are you using mac, windows, linux, FreeBSD?

Comment: I am running the static main method of the class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`. I am running it in IntelliJ Idea 2016.3 Ultimate edition on ubuntu 16.04 LTE. See here https://github.com/joekienzle/lawyd/blob/feature/simpleVaadinUi/src/main/java/net/lawyd/server/LawydServerApplication.java

Comment: Sounds right. I use Eclipse and either start a SB project using the command line or creating a M2 run script from Eclipse. But IntelliJ is easier in that regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the root problem: Jersey was mapped to the root, so all the calls on root were intercepted. Changing the `@ApplicationPath("/api")` to something other than root solved the problem:

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
```